# Finding the slope of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

How do I find the slope of this function:

$px + (2p-1)y + 4 = 0$

I need to know how to answer a previous question of mine (also posted on this forum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first rearrange so that $y$ is on the left hand side:

$$(2p-1)y = px - 4$$

Then divide through by $2p-1$:

$$y = \frac{-p}{2p-1} x - \frac{4}{2p-1}$$

The slope of the line is the coefficient of $x$ in this equation.

Note that this only works if $2p-1\neq 0$ (because you can't divide by zero), which means that you need $p\neq 1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that how this a line, is only,
\begin{eqnarray}
px + (2p-1)y+4=0 &\Leftrightarrow& y = \dfrac{-p}{(2p-1)}x + \dfrac{4}{(2p-1)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Then the slop is $ \dfrac{-p}{(2p-1)}$, isn't it?

Comment: seems so, I would mention $p\neq 0.5$

Comment: change 4 to -4 ;)

Answer (score 1):

For a straight line given by equation $Ax+By+C=0$ the slope coefficient equals $-\frac{A}{B}$

Answer (score 0):

Do you know *scalar-* or *inner product*?

The equation is $\langle (p,2p-1); (x,y)\rangle = -4$, and this is parallel to the plain containing the origo $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid \langle (p,2p-1); (x,y)\rangle = 0\}$.
And satisfying this equation means that the vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ is *perpendicular* to $(p,2p-1)$, so this latter is the *normalvector* of the line..

Answer (score 0):

you could differentiate it:

$$px + (2p-1)y + 4 = 0$$
$$p + (2p-1)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
giving:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{p}{2p-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of slope,you need to find the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for your curve.To find that out,just differentiate both sides with respect to $x$,then we'll get:

$p+(2p-1)y'=0$

It can be solved for $y'$.
Important thing though is if $p$ is a function rather than a constant,then while differentiating,we'll have to use chain rules,etc, and proceed similarly.